# Can't connect to geth JSON RPC from React Native Expo

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am using the `ethers` library on npm to connect. My code for testing the connection is as follows

```
  let result = await ethers.utils._fetchData(
    {
      url: "https://MY_URL",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    },
    ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(
      '{ "id": 42, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_chainId", "params": [ ] }'
    )
  );
  console.log(result);
  console.log("Text", ethers.utils.toUtf8String(result));
```

Both results come back as empty though.